# Relation between residual stress and von mises stress calculated by FEA in comercial software

Tags: structural-engineering, computer-engineering

Suppose we do nonlinear structure mechanics computation.

In each time step, we can get the results and can get Von Mises Stress at each node of the mesh. Can we say this number also means its residual stress?

If not, is there any way to get residual stress?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The Von Mises Stress and the residual stress are not the same thing.

To get the residual stress, do another time step where all the applied loads are zero. If there is material nonlinearity (plasticity or creep) the stresses and deflections will not return to zero when you remove all the loads.

Comment: von Mises begins with small 'v', he belonged to royal family.